# Post a node in two sites

Tags: nodes

I have two sites.I want,when posting a node to one site,this node to be automatically posted in also to the other site and vice versa.How can I do that?Does this need web services?
thanks

Comment: is content type field are equal in two sites?
what is the differences between two website?
why you always post on one site, and in second site get  data( nodes) form first one?

Comment: Yes,content type fields are equal to the two sites.The sites are jobboards,one general jobboard and the second niche jobboard.I want the jobs posted on the niche jobbard also being posted in the general jobboard and vice versa.Thanks

Comment: what is your drupal version? are your database on the same server?

Comment: Drupal version is 7 .No,databases are not on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with web services but that will require a fair bit of work. You can easily achieve this functionality by using a [domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module.

This will allow you to publish a node to multiple domains.